# How to copy QT folder to another folder without reinstalling it?

Tags: windows, qt, installation

I have QT installed on disc D (on Windows). And I want to move it to disc C. Is it possible to do that?

If I just copy QT folder from C to D then I see lot of errors when I compile my applications that use QT. 
Errors are because qmake.exe contains full paths to include, bin and libs folders inside. So, when I create solution for Visual Studio 2005 using qmake - then this solution contains dependencies to old QT folder from disc D. And I found no way how to remove this dependencies without reinstalling of QT.

It is not a big problem for one my single machine - I can reinstall. But I need to deliver this change then to tens and hundreds of other developers machines and I want to make it as easy as possible without need to reinstall QT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess re-compiling qmake will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, recompiling qmake solves it. But it takes time to recompile. But probably it is the only way. Thanks.

Comment: Compiling qmake does not take long time. Do not re-compile all of the qt libraries, only compile qmake.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `%PATH%`environment variable. You should have something like D:\qt\qt-4.5.3\bin in it. Just change it to your new path. Et voilà!

Comment: No, it doesn't help because path to libs and includes are stored inside qmake.exe (it is very stupid, don't know why qmake developers did that). So, if I just change %PATH% then it helps to find qmake.exe but doesn't help to build projects generated with it.

Comment: Even if you use the environment variable `%QTDIR%` ?

Comment: Yes, qmake is using %QTDIR% only to find compiler specifications. But include and library path is hardcoded inside qmake...

Answer (score 1):

Downloads QtMove from www.runfastsoft.com and everything can be done in one minute.

I've used it in several PCs to relocate different version of Qt, works fine!